# Temporarily disable and enable event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wonder how I can disable and enable a jQuery event? I have this code which is already working under page ready:

```
$(".panzoom").panzoom({
    $zoomIn: $(".zoom-in"),
    $zoomOut: $(".zoom-out"),
    $zoomRange: $(".zoom-range"),
    $reset: $(".reset")
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="select">
    <img src="img/svg/painter/anchor.svg">
</button>
```

I want to change it so that when I click in the `#select` button the `.panzoom` is  temporarily disabled. How can I do this?

Comment: `$(".panzoom").panzoom("disable");` and to re-enable `$(".panzoom").panzoom("enable");`

Comment: @RayonDabre You mean put ur code in onclick event !

Comment: May be.. Depends on your requirement...

Comment: When do you want to reenable the event?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is already support for this in the panzoom library:

```js
var panzoomDisabled = false;

$('#select').on('click', function() {
  if (panzoomDisabled) {
    $(".panzoom").panzoom("enable");
  } else {
    $(".panzoom").panzoom("disable");
  }
  
  panzoomDisabled = !panzoomDisabled;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="select">
    <img src="img/svg/painter/anchor.svg">
</button>
```